# how to replace the first start of string in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

I am using this command to replace the string from PostgreSQL column:

```
update sentence 
set sentence_en = replace(sentence_en,"1.  ","")
```

but I just want to replace the first occure from left start of table column. what should I do to make it work as expect? the desire result I want when the `sentence_en` like this: `1.  xxxxxx1.  xxxx1.`  , the result may like this: `xxxxxx1.  xxxx1.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#:~:text=%7Bbar%7D%0A%20%7Bbaz%7D-,regexp_replace,-(%20string%20text%2C%20pattern) function with no additional flags.

```
select regexp_replace('1.  xxxxxx1.  xxxx1.  ', '1.  ', '');
```

returns:

```
xxxxxx1.  xxxx1.
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20ea049ead501d6ca5f608bea7160f9c)*

Answer (score 1):

regexp_replace can do this.
Use the '^' [anchor character](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to ensure that your replacement only happens at the start of the string.

```
update sentence 
set sentence_en = regexp_replace('^1.  ', '', '' );
```